# .net file rename for don't watch(FileSystemWatcher)

Tags: filesystemwatcher

i'm use Directory.Move  << this watched filesystemwatcher log

Log details  full path = e:\web\qe1  type rename  old name = web\folder ...

how to bypass filesystemwatcher log ??

Comment: What log? Please be more clear and post your code.

Comment: Still don't understand. What are you trying to do exactly? Are you creating a log file? Post your full code.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras
Thank you for your reply.
I didn't see that until too late... sorry

The issue has been resolved. 
It wasn't a code issue, it was an issue with the permissions of the watched folder being forced to change. 

Also, the permissions were changed at the kernel level, so I couldn't modify them at the OS level.